# Counting collection tags in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to count and list the tags inside a Collection called `_note` in Jekyll. I'm extremely close, I think, to solving it, but I'm getting a little tripped up on the actual counting of the tags (listing unique tags works fine) and could use a second pair of eyes to look at the liquid markup and see what I'm missing.

Tags in the `_note` YAML header are organized as:

`tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4]`

Thus far:

```
<!-- Create empty arrays -->
{% assign tags = '' | split: ',' %}
{% assign unique_tags = '' | split: ',' %}
{% assign counter = 0 %}

<!-- Map and flatten -->
{% assign note_tags =  site.note | map: 'tags' | join: ','  | split: ',' %}

<!-- Push to tags -->
{% for tag in note_tags '%}
  {% assign tags = tags | push: tag %}
{% endfor %}

<!-- Uniq -->
{% assign tags = tags | sort %}
{% for tag in tags %}
  <!-- If not equal to previous then it must be unique -->
  {% unless tag == previous %}    
    <!-- Push to unique_tags and count -->
    {% assign unique_tags = unique_tags | push: tag %}
    {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
  {% endunless %}
  {% assign previous = tag %}
{% endfor %}

{% for tag in unique_tags %}
  {{ tag }} ({{ counter }}
{% endfor %}
```

Using the `size` method in liquid doesn't seem to return the correct value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### New answer

```
{% comment %}map, flatten and sort{% endcomment %}
{% assign tags =  site.note | map: 'tags' | join: ','  | split: ',' | sort %}
{% assign previousTag = "" %}
{% assign counter = 0 %}

{% for currentTag in tags %}

  {% comment %}first loop : initializing previousTag{% endcomment %}
  {% if previousTag == "" %}
    {% assign previousTag = currentTag %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if currentTag == previousTag %}
    {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
  {% else %}
    {{ previousTag }} ({{ counter }})
    {% assign counter = 1 %}
  {% endif %}

  {% comment %}last loop : flushing what's left to print{% endcomment %}
  {% if forloop.last %}
    {{ currentTag }} ({{ counter }})
  {% endif %}

  {% assign previousTag = currentTag %}

{% endfor %}
```

#### Old answer (did I missed something in the question : Yes !)

[Liquid uniq filter](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#uniq) to the rescue !

```
{% assign uniq_tags = site.note
                      | map: 'tags'
                      | join: ","
                      | split: ","
                      | uniq %}

<p>{{ uniq_tags | array_to_sentence_string }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your note. Would there be a way to extend this so I can count the occurrences of each unique tag? So I could display, for example, both the tag and the number of times that tag appears?

Comment: Sorry I missed your question. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Fantastic, that does it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

I use Jekyll on my GitHub-hosted page, you can use `group_by` to achieve so:

```
{% assign alldocs = site.COLLECTIONNAME | <additional filtering and sorting> %} 
{% assign grouptag =  alldocs | map: 'tags' | join: ','  | split: ','  | group_by: tag %}
{%- for tag in grouptag -%}
    <h1>{{- tag.name -}} - {{tag.size}}</h1>
    {%- for document in alldocs -%}
        {% if document.tags contains tag.name %}
             <p>{{- document.title -}}
         {% endif %}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Live example of a tag cloud including all the content of my blog (posts and projects) [here](https://dieghernan.github.io/tags)

Comment: Great Answer. Single Line.

Comment: Concise and readable. This, by far, is the superior solution.